# Select option selecionado

Tags: php, mysql, select, option

Eu preciso deixar o select option selecionado de acordo com o campo gravado no mysql. O formulário é para editar pos isso ele apresenta os campos disponíveis com o foreach.

Ex:

```
 <select name="segurado"  >
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php foreach ($result as $rs) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rs["nome"]; ?>"><?php echo $rs["nome"]; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Desta forma o select mostra os campos da tabela segurados mas eu quero deixar o campo do registro selecionado para edição selecionado.

---

Talvez eu não tenha me feito entender direito: eu recupero o campo gravado no mysql e consigo colocá-lo no label do select mas não é esta a solução. Mas isso mostra que a variável para comparar é correta, ou seja a que foi gravada na tabela quando do cadastro. Como eu quero editar o registro, preciso que este campo gravado e recuperado seja setado como selected no options, que por sua vez está sendo alimentado pelo foreach e criando os elementos da mesma forma que no cadastro. Abaixo o exemplo de como preencho o option:

```
                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM seguradoras ORDER BY nome";
                            try {
                                $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
                                $stmt->execute();
                                $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
                            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                                echo($ex->getMessage());
                            }
```

Com ele preenchido, quero que ele mostre a variável que vem do banco no caso $residencial->seguradora

Melhorou galera ?

Answer (score 0):

Quando atender a condição que você quer selecionar 
coloque  o `<option selected>`

```
<select name="segurado"  >
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php foreach ($result as $rs) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rs["nome"]; ?>" <?php if($rs["minha_opcao_selecionada"] === true ){ echo "selected"}  ?>  ><?php echo $rs["nome"]; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Zoy, o seu código está apresentando um erro de sintaxe mas não consegui identificar.

Comment: Já descobri. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Ficou assim:<option value="<?php echo $rs["nome"]; ?>" <?php if ($residencial->segurado == $rs["nome"] ) { echo "selected";}  ?>  ><?php echo $rs["nome"]; ?></option>    Faltava o ponto e vírgula após o echo "selected"  Valeu Zoy, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que você abastece seu formulário com com entradas na tabela você poderia ter um campo especifico para isto tipo `select` com **on** ou **off** ou por verificando o item mesmo exemplos:

```
<?php
    // sua lógica de acesso ao banco...
?>
<select name="segurado">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php 
        foreach ($result as $rs) {
            // caso use um campo especifico
            if ( $rs['select'] === 'on' ) {
                echo '<option value="' . $rs['nome'] . '" selected="true">' . $rs['nome'] .'</option>';
            } else {
                echo '<option value="' . $rs['nome'] . '">' . $rs['nome'] .'</option>';
            }
            // ou pelo item mesmo
            if ( $rs['nome_do_item'] ) {
                echo '<option value="' . $rs['nome'] . '" selected="true">' . $rs['nome'] .'</option>';
            } else {
                echo '<option value="' . $rs['nome'] . '">' . $rs['nome'] .'</option>';
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Lauro, vou tentar mais um pouco antes de optar por criar o campo com on off

Answer (score 0):

Se quiseres uma opção compacta aqui tens uma:

```
<select name="segurado">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php foreach ($result as $rs): ?>
        <option value="<?=$rs['nome']?>" <?= ($rs['select'] == 'on') ?  'selected' : '' ?> ><?= $rs['nome'] ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: 13dev, o seu código está selecionando o primeiro registro da tabela e duplicando todos.

Comment: editado tenta agora assim

Answer (score 0):

Bom, alterando o código e substituindo as variáveis finalmente consegui o resultado que queria:

```
<?php foreach ($results as $rs) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rs["nome"]; ?>" <?php if ($residencial->seguradora == $rs["nome"] ) { echo "selected";}  ?>  ><?php echo $rs["nome"]; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Muito obrigado a todos e um forte abraço !